# Determine which element of an array will make IF statement return true Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have no idea what to Google for this.
I have an array with 5 number more to be added. I would like to check to see if any of the elements can be multiplied by y to make x. (if possible the element index to be returned that make the if statement true)

//all most like the "every" but for single elements

//sorry for this crap worded question

Comment: Lots of ways to do it. Can even do it in a simple `for()` loop. Show us what you have tried and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Maybe you could add pseudo code regarding what do you exactly want. What condition do you want the new element to pass

Comment: [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)?

Comment: You are looking for [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: Could you return the index of the element(s) that are true with some?

Comment: No, you would need to use a [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) loop to accomplish that. If you need both, you should just utilize a standard `for` loop. Using this allows you to exit the loop early saving unnecessary computations if you just want the first index.

Comment: You can also use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to just get only the elements which fit that condition.

Comment: @bergi includes?  elem*y=x , elem=x/y ...

Comment: @Jonasw If `y` and `x` are constant, yes why not.

Comment: @bergi i was just wondering that im the first one with that idea..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use forEach to get all elements that fit the condition:

```
const arr = [12,59,42,53,6];
const x = 24;
const y = 4;

arr.forEach(function(item, index){
  if(item * y === x) {
    console.log(item, index);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Originally i thought using `array.some()` would help but as mentioned below - `some()` is used for returning a `boolean` and shouldn't be used to return anything else. Working with my colleague, Dan - we found using `array.findIndex()` instead helped us with this...

```js
let input = [5, 35, 6, 7, 8];
let x = 24;
let y = 4;

let multiplies = (x, y) => number => number * y === x;

let index = input.findIndex(multiplies(x, y));

console.log(index);
```

Comment: You need to return a boolean from the `some` callback.

Comment: I see what you're saying. have edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple if you use the [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function.

```
function mult(y, x) {
  return function mult(element, index, array) {
    return element * y === x;
  }
}

[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(mult(10, 50)); //True since 5 * 10 = 50
[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(mult(10, 100)); //False since [none of elements] * 10 = 100
```

Warning: The above example utilizes [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

You can use the above function to extract only the correct entries via. [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].filter(mult(10, 50)); //[5]
[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].filter(mult(10, 100)); //[]
```

You can also utilize the above function to get which ones solve the problem via. [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].map(mult(10, 50)); //[false, true, false, false, false]
[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].map(mult(10, 100)); //[false, false, false, false, false]
```

You can even take it a step further by getting only the indicies of those that fulfill your criterion via. [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
function getIndicies(a, e, i) {
    if (e)
        a.push(i);
    return a;
};

[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].map(mult(10, 50)).reduce(getIndicies, []); //[1]
[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].map(mult(10, 100)).reduce(getIndicies, []); //[]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can do this is to write a general function that returns another function that you can use in your calculation.

`multiplyByNumIsResult` accepts the arguments for `y` and `r` (your result), and returns another function that accepts `x`. `x` is the element of the array that you'll be checking.

```
const multiplyByNumIsResult = (y, r) => {
  return (x) => {
    return x * y === r;
  }
}
```

This allows you to create new functions with specific names based on how `multiplyByNumIsResult` is called. Here's one called `by7Is49`.

```
const by7Is49 = multiplyByNumIsResult(7, 49);
```

Another function could be `by3Is9`:

```
const by3Is9 = multiplyByNumIsResult(3, 9);
```

You're basically just using that general function to as a factory to make new bespoke functions.

```
const arr = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
```

If you use `map` you can return a new array that gives you the result of checking each element with the function.

```
const result = arr.map(by7Is49); // [ false, false, false, true, false ]
```

While this gives you a decent result, it could be better.

If you change the general function slightly, you can get a better result - an array that contains only the indices that fulfil the condition.

```
const multiplyByNumIsResult = (y, r) => {
  return (p, c, i) => {
    if (c * y === r) p.push(i);
    return p;
  }
}

const result2 = arr2.reduce(by7Is49, []); // [ 3 ]
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9sxoop7L/)

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayElem * y = x
ArrayElem = x / y;
```

So we actually just need to to check if that number (ArrayElem) is in that array. For that we can use includes:

```
var array=[1,2,3,4],
       x=8,y=2;

if(array.includes(x/y)) alert("wohoo");//wohoo as 4*2=8
```

Getting its index is an ease:

```
array.indexOf(x/y) //3 as array[3] =4
```

Best (concerning performance)  would actually be a Set:

```
var set = new Set(array);
if(set.has(x/y)) alert("wohoo");
```